# How to change a decimal value so it ends in a specified digit?

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I have a decimal value stored in 'amount' and another decimal value called 'roundTo'.
I'm trying to take whatever 'amount' is, round it to whatever 'roundTo' is set to and then set the final value in newAmount, but it should round to the closest value to roundTo.

Ex.

> amount = 2.01
>
> roundTo = 0.09
>
> newAmount becomes 1.99

Ex.

> amount = 2.07
>
> roundTo = 0.09
>
> newAmount becomes 2.09

I'm trying to get it to work with all possible values, so roundTo can be anything from 0.01 to 0.09

I've tried doing this like

```
newAmount = (Math.Round(amount * 10m) / 10m - 0.01m);
```

The above only really works for when roundTo is 0.09 (using a switch case where if roundTo was 0.09, the above would run).

I also tried

```
newAmount = Math.Round(amount / roundTo, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * roundTo;
```

But didn't get any good data from this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!!

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @Arvis I mention what the result should be as 'newAmount'. 
For example, amount = 2.01 roundTo = 0.09 newAmount becomes 1.99.
Another example is amount = 2.07 roundTo = 0.09 newAmount becomes 2.09

Comment: Shift,  round,  shift back. That is: if round to is 0.3, Subtract 0.3 from the number, round it, then add 0.3 to the rounded number.

Comment: E.g.: 0.47 - 0.03 = 0.44 rounded to 0.40 + 0.03 = 0.43 and 0.49 - 0.03 = 0.46 rounded 0.50 + 0.03 = 0.53

Comment: Or your example: 2.01-0.09 = 1.92 rounded 1.90 + 0.09 = 1.99

Answer (score 0):

```
    decimal amount = 2.06m;
    decimal roundTo = 0.04m;

    decimal newAmount = Math.Round(amount - roundTo, 1) + roundTo;
```